# Swap Function Utilizing Pointers

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, generics, swap

So, for an assignment I have to write a template function that will successfully swap two values of any type. I also have to verify that pointers can be used by this function as well. Apparently, thorough output will demonstrate swapping of the pointers, but not swapping of the values they point-to.

I have a general idea of how to start, but not where to go afterwords.

Here's what I have so far.

```
template <typename T>

void swap(T*& first, T*& second) 
{

T* a = nullptr;

a = first;
first = second;
second = a;

std::cout << first << " " << second << " ";



}
```

I've got the function prototype, but don't know what to do from here, any suggestions on how to call this function and if it would actually provide me the desired output?

Here's my main

```
int main()
{
    swap(10, 20);

    system("pause");

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to call your pointer swap function?

Comment: @user0042 That, and if this logic would actually work regarding the assignment

Comment: Did you try some code to call it? What were your specific problems? The logic of the template function looks correct.

Comment: @user0042 Yeah, im not exactly sure how to call a function that uses generics. I posted what my main looks like.

Comment: Your function want's pointers to `T`, so call it with pointers not with literal values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template function wants pointers to `T` as parameters. Your code

```
int main()
{
    swap(10, 20);

    system("pause");

}
```

doesn't call it with pointers but integer literal values. What you should use to call your function is

```
int main() {
    int var1 = 42;
    int var2 = 15;
    int* pvar1 = &var1;
    int* pvar2 = &var2;

    swap(pvar1,pvar2);
}
```